# persistence.xml dependency in maven test

Tags: unit-testing, maven, jpa

Consider this structure:

```
/project
   /module-1
      /src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
   /module-2
```

In module-1 test jar is created. 
module-1/pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

This test jar is a dependency in module-2/pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.domain.test</groupId>
<artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
<type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Problem is that in tests of module-2, persitence units(PU) defined in /src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml cannot be found. PU are created programatically:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnit);
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

How can I get it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency you declared is not targetting the test-jar you created.
You should declared it like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.domain.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-shared</artifactId>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```